# VB Method naming suggestion

Tags: vb.net, methods, naming

I have a Method that:

- checks if data are modified
- if yes, asks the user: "Do you want to save?" (Y/N/Cancel)
- if answer is yes, it saves the data
- returns a boolean value whether the user has answered "Cancel", in which case the caller method needs to abort its Form.Close() event.

Problems (interconnected together):

- I can't think of a proper name for the method.
- It does many things at the same time.
- The boolean return type is not very clear. I could directly return the user's answer, but it will be slightly more complicated to use, because the caller has to compare the return value of the function with the Cancel constant instead of comparing to True.

Do you have any suggestions? Thank you!

```
Private Function CancelDueToUnsaved() As Boolean
    If Not _data.Modified Then Return False

    Dim answ = MsgBox("Save changes?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel + MsgBoxStyle.Question, "")

    If answ = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then SaveData()

    Return (answ = MsgBoxResult.Cancel)
End Function

Private Sub Form_Closing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    If CancelDueToUnsaved() Then e.Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: A bit of an opinion based question, but in your shoes I would just name it SaveChanges. There is no use in trying to cover all the functionality in the method name. Cover the basic action, that should do it. Notice that I also reversed the boolean and focus on the actual saving and not the cancelation... but this is just my opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would name it something like "SaveChanges" (as Tom mentioned) because it should show that the save data action happens here. Also a named parameter may improve readability if that's important:

```
Private Sub SaveChanges(ByRef cancelled as Boolean)
...
End Sub
```

You could also throw custom exception but it would be too much for a single boolean:

```
Private Sub SaveChanges()
...
If answ = MsgBoxResult.Cancel Then Throw New UserCancelException
...
End Sub
```

Comment: The byref parameter is very elegant considering readability and effectiveness. Very good point!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a very common situation; in my forms I have solved using two functions:

```
Function SaveChanges() As Boolean

    SaveChanges = False

    'check if data compiled is ok
    'save changes under transaction
    '(...)

    'if everything is ok
    SaveChanges = True

End Function

Function blnExitMode() As Boolean

    blnExitMode = True

    'code to check if there are changes to save
    '(...)

    'if there are changes to save
    Select Case MsgBox("Save changes?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel + MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton3)
        Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
            If Not Me.SaveChanges Then blnExitMode = False

        Case MsgBoxResult.Cancel
            blnExitMode = False

    End Select

End Function
```

So I can use this code on form closing:

```
If Not Me.blnExitMode Then e.Cancel() = True
```

I can also call `blnExitMode` when a user try to move to another record without saving changes or change form 'modality' (i.e. from insert to search).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are simply saying "when the form is closed, if changes have been made that were not saved, prompt the user whether to save or not or not close the form.  If Yes, save changes and close, if No, do not save but close anyway, if Cancel, do not save or close."  Yes?

You could easily accomplish this within the form closing event itself instead of calling something else and trying to pass the response (which to your point is a little difficult since you are trying to use a boolean but there are 3 options).

This is how I've accomplished this myself...hopefully this helps:

```
Private Sub Form_Closing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

    If _data.Modified Then
        Dim dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(Me, "Changes have been made.  Would you like to save?", "Unsaved Changes", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

        If dialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            SaveData()

        ElseIf dialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
            e.Cancel = True

        Else
            'result is No - don't do anything...just let the form close
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Good point indeed. But I use the function in two spots. Not only in Form.Close() but also upon pressing the button "reset" (=read data again from db and overwrite possible changes). So I don't want to duplicate the check-if-modified code in these 2 spots.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

- Using a simple name denoting the main task: I preferred HandleUnsavedChanges() from simply SaveChanges()
- Using a ByRef parameter for returning if user cancelled.

Note: I have also been using this code in the event of clicking the Reset Button, where a simple question OK/Cancel fits better. But I discarded the button anyway, because it didn't make much sense. So, the method HandleUnsavedChanges could now in fact be transferred inside the event of Form.Close().

```
Private Sub HandleUnsavedChanges(ByRef userCancelled As Boolean)
    If Not _data.IsModified Then Exit Sub

    Dim answ = MsgBox(msg, MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel + MsgBoxStyle.Question, "Bestätigung")
    Select Case answ
        Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
            SaveData()
        Case MsgBoxResult.Cancel
            userCancelled = True
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Closing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    HandleUnsavedChanges(userCancelled:=e.Cancel)
End Sub
```